# What happen if I have a container with "content-visibility: auto" that is inside of a container with "content-visibility:auto"?

Tags: html, css, performance

Let's assume I have a sub-containers inside a container with content-visibility:auto as following:

```html
<div class="container" style="content-visibility: auto; contain-intrinsic-size: 50px 2000px">
    <div class="sub-container" style="content-visibility: auto; contain-intrinsic-size: 50px 1000px">
    <div class="sub-container" style="content-visibility: auto; contain-intrinsic-size: 50px 1000px">
</div>
```

Will the browser will wait with the rendering of the sub-containers until the sub-container reaches the view-port?

Answer (score -1):

No, the browser will not wait. It will be displayed simultaneously.

Comment: So it is a bad practice / redundant to put content-visibility: auto; inside a content-visibility: auto;?

Comment: Also, I would be happy to get a link to your resource...

Comment: sameermanandhar?

Comment: the container <div> with class  'sub-container' does not need to have the "content-visibility:auto". this is redundant.